# Android Layouts for different Screen Sizes on BlackBerry?

Tags: android, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-android

I am using `layout` folder for phone layouts and `layout-sw600dp` folder for tablet layouts.

Android picks the layout file with respect to the screen size. I installed the app on `PlayBook` using Android RunTime Environment. Playbook still picks up the layout from `layout` folder.

Do I need to do something different for playbook?

Answer (score 2):

`layout-sw600dp` is a Android 3.2 feature (API 13). Blackberry's Android runtime only supports 2.3.3 (API 10).

http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/mastertopic_2016760_11.html

Comment: Thanks Morrison. I didn't think of it. So, what can I do for different layout for playbook?

Comment: Test in emulator/device. For an existing Android code base you may need to keep a separate branch for Blackberry releases - with the associated maintenance issues.

Comment: Yes I do have a separate branch. But the reason y i need different layout folders is that I wanna support both BB10 phones and playbooks.  Do you think I need to release separately for BB10 Phones and separately for PlayBook (BB10/2.0)?